# notepad++ find number greater than a specific number between specific columns

Tags: regex, text, macros, notepad++

It would be nice if somebody give me advice, how to mark lines (or numbers) between columns 13 to 22 (columns 1), and 46 to 55 (columns 2) with the result greater then 5.65 using regular expression.

I marked the columns with dots. My file structure is always the same between "*** "

Take a look at the following table:

[image: table with dots]

I tried to post in normal way, but all the numbers get messy, so I decided to make a print screen. Sorry for that.

I have a txt file:

---

```
        Columns 1                         Columns 2
14  TOP:   0.12      2.7   -11.1    13      0.14      2.8   -11.1    13
15  TOP:   6.24      6.4   -81.7    13      0.32      2.5     1.6    13
16  TOP:   0.00      8.7  -114.8    13      5.78      3.0    13.6    13
17  TOP:   0.00      1.9  -113.7    13      0.33      3.2    -2.7    13
18  TOP:  18.09     -1.7  -112.7    13      0.28      2.7    -2.1    13
```

The result should be:

```
15  TOP:   6.24      6.4   -81.7    13      0.32      2.5     1.6    13
16  TOP:   0.00      8.7  -114.8    13      5.78      3.0    13.6    13
18  TOP:  18.09     -1.7  -112.7    13      0.28      2.7    -2.1    13
```

Comment: Regex is not well-suited for evaluating numbers. Why aren't you doing this in a spreadsheet? Also, have you tried to solve this on your own yet? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: I've got a working regex for this, but I kinda feel like this sort of question shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: Hi Dane, I tryed to my own to read on google and learn regex, but without luck. I calculate constructions and simetimes I want to check the result by my own. Progam gives txt file. So I dont want to use excel or other software to convert to other format. It would be nice to have the same txt file with needed lines. Notepad++ have abilities to run macro, but I am not a programmer. Mabe you can share your regex?

Comment: easy job for awk, if you have to do it in a text editor, it's the right time to switch to vim

Comment: This is really a "right tool for the job" issue. You should either pop this into a spreadsheet or use a programming/scripting language to process the file. Just because I can't help myself, here's the regex I wrote that will match your lines: https://www.debuggex.com/r/za7MNPOOthBGjiMU